# Laravel 5 RESTful Resource Controllers subset actions not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a middleware that checks for route's subset action's

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $requests = $request->route()->getAction();
        $userPermissions = Session::get('userPermissions');
        $module = $requests['module'];
        $permission= $requests['permission'];
}
```

I have a my route as

```
 Route::resource('/users', 'BackEnd\'UsersController', ['module' => 'acl', 'permission'=>'createUser']);
```

This is what I get when I dump the request

```
array (size=7)
  'middleware' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'authentication' (length=14)
      1 => string 'authorization' (length=13)
  'as' => string 'user.index' (length=10)
  'uses' => string 'App\Http\Controllers\BackEnd'UsersController@index' (length=50)
  'controller' => string 'App\Http\Controllers\BackEnd'UsersController@index' (length=50)
  'namespace' => string 'App\Http\Controllers' (length=20)
  'prefix' => string '/' (length=1)
  'where' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

what I am missing is the 'module' and 'permission' in that array If  I use a differnt route say

```
 Route::get('/users/all', ['uses'=> 'BackEnd\UsersController@index',
     'module'=>'acl',
            'permission'=>'createUser'

        ]);
```

this is the dumped result of the request which is what I want using the resource route.

```
array (size=8)
  'middleware' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'authentication' (length=14)
      1 => string 'authorization' (length=13)
  'uses' => string 'App\Http\Controllers\BackEnd\UsersController@index' (length=50)
  'module' => string 'acl' (length=3)
  'permission' => string 'createUser' (length=10)
  'controller' => string 'App\Http\Controllers\BackEnd\UsersController@index' (length=50)
  'namespace' => string 'App\Http\Controllers' (length=20)
  'prefix' => null
  'where' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource has some problem with options.
You can use sth like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth', 'modules'=>'testt'], function() {
    Route::resource('/te', 'HomeController');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I was having problem with resource so I thought there might be some other way I had thought of this alternative but still thanks again